# Paypal Express checkout | Wrong order ID: “x”

Tags: magento, paypal

I am running a magento store and getting issues with PayPal. Payments are being taken but no order is created.

I am getting this error in the log:

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception: Wrong order ID: "000002353". in /domains/domain.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php:140
```

The order with that number does not exist. (Skipped)

I found this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214182/wrong-order-id-paypal-ipn-exception-magento-2 but it doesn't really provide a solution to the problem. I am running on **Magento ver. 2.1.8**

Anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue where the Payment was captured but the order was not created.

I had to refund a lot of customers and the exception here is from the PayPal IPN that is trying to add a IPN number to an order that does not exist.

To fix the problem, I followed the following article to set up the IPN on the PayPal account: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNSetup/

Comment: this doesnt sound like an answer just a repeat of the question

Comment: Hi @bjornredemption - You are correct, I added the link I used to fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I found the issue is

```
Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'sequence_value' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_invoice_1` () VALUES ()
```

Then I go to table sequence_invoice_1 and have changed type of "sequence_value" from int(10) to bigint(20). Now, it works fine.

Our customer have a lot order migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. That is an issue.

Comment: int(10) is correct for a 10 digit order number - your answer (which you have pasted all over the web about this problem) is incorrect otherwise this error would occur with all orders and not just Paypal ones.

Comment: Maybe you have another issue. It works for my issue. So I add it here and hope it can help someone! In my case I only have this issue with Paypal.